# How to draw an image on the applet

Tags: java, awt, paint, bufferedimage

```
public class ImageExample2 extends Applet
{

    BufferedImage bi;


    public void init ()
    {

        resize (500, 500);

        try
        {

            BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read (new File ("G:\\Java\\WhatDotColour\\Pacman.PNG"));
        }
        catch (java.io.IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
    }


    public void paint (Graphics g)
    {

        g.drawImage (bi, 20, 140, this); //.drawImage(in, 0, 0, null);

    }
}
```

Everytime I try to run it, it gives me a null pointer exception. How can I fix it?

Comment: make bi a class var ( ie global )

Comment: I'm new to Java, so I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: actually, it is already, see my answer...

Comment: **instance variable is not initialized at all.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't** mix `Applet` with `File`. They are just like oil & water. Applet runs in the browser. Always use relative path.

Use [Applet#getCodeBase()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#getCodeBase%28%29) to gets the base URL. This is the URL of the directory which contains this applet.

Sample code: (look at the output of getCodeBase() method and modify the image path)

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;

public class ImageExample2 extends Applet {

    private Image bi;

    public void init() {

        resize(500, 500);

        System.out.println(getCodeBase()); // file:/D:/Workspace/JavaProject/bin/

        // This the actual code that should be used to read the image in Applet
        bi = getImage(getCodeBase(), "images/222.png");
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(bi, 20, 140, this);

    }
}
```

If you are using Windows & Eclipse IDE then look at the screenshot shown below for above sample code image path.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
BufferedImage bi=ImageIO.read (new File ("G:\\Java\\WhatDotColour\\Pacman.PNG"));
```

to

```
bi = ImageIO.read (new File ("G:\\Java\\WhatDotColour\\Pacman.PNG"));
```

and change

```
g.drawImage (bi, 20, 140, this); //.drawImage(in, 0, 0, null);
```

to

```
if (bi!=null) g.drawImage (bi, 20, 140, this); //.drawImage(in, 0, 0, null);
```